# Number of Seconds since epoch in solaris 10

Tags: solaris, date

I am trying to get the number of seconds since the epoch in both Solaris 10 and Solaris 11.

On Solaris 11, "date +%s" is giving me the output (from bash), but the same is failing on Solaris 10.

What is the right command in Solaris 10?

Comment: I have a C program for this which uses SIGUSR1 to output to the screen if you want...

Comment: Please review suggested answers and mark one as solution if it works for you. Otherwise add comments so we can further improve the answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use `nawk`:

```
nawk "BEGIN{print srand}"
```

More portably in POSIX shells (such as `/usr/xpg4/bin/sh` on Solaris 10):

```
command -p awk 'BEGIN{srand(); print srand()}'
```

(on Solaris 10, from `/bin/sh` which was the Bourne shell, you would invoke `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` to get a standard `awk` (the one in `/bin` being an ancient one from the 70s), or do `` PATH=`getconf PATH`${PATH+:$PATH} `` for the standard utilities including `awk` to be preferred over the ancient ones; that also applies to Solaris 11 where `/bin/sh` is no longer an ancient shell but most of the other tools in `/bin` still are).

Comment: Gives a syntax error at my end?

Comment: I just ran it on my solaris 10 cluster and it worked. Can you verify you don't miss typed it?

Comment: I appreciate the OP's query is specifically about Solaris, so it's a valid answer, but that format doesn't work on Linux and if I use `srand()` I get 1 as the output.  I believe it's using an undocumented feature, rather than a function for which it's designed and may not be reliable long-term.  Are you sure you ran `srand` and not `srand()`?

Comment: Thank you for your remark. I don't think it does matter are you using `srand` or `srand()`. Still i tested it both ways on my solaris 10 test server and it worked.

Comment: @EightBitTony The use of `srand` to get time of day via `nawk` is documented in the [Solaris nawk man page](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/816-5165/nawk-1.html#scrolltoc).

Answer (score 0):

I usually revert to `perl` for this, assuming it is installed.

`perl -e 'print time."\n";'`

For example,

```
$ perl -e 'print time."\n";'
1457531088
```

Assuming `perl` is installed, it should be pretty much OS independent .

Answer (score 0):

Both Solaris 10 and 11 should come with zsh as long as it's not a minimal install (in which case it wouldn't come with bash either), so you could switch to that there the current epoch time is in the `$EPOCHSECONDS` special variable after you've loaded the `zsh/datetime` module.

```
$ zmodload zsh/datetime
$ echo $EPOCHSECONDS
1684393493
```

That module also comes with a `strftime` builtin that can format that `$EPOCHSECONDS` into a human representation or with `-r` convert a human representation back to epoch seconds.

In Solaris 11, `ksh` and `sh` are `ksh93` and in Solaris 10, `/usr/dt/bin/dtksh` (if a graphical environment is available) should be based on `ksh93` (an ancient version though). `ksh93`'s `printf` builtin can also format and parse dates.

```
printf '%(%s)T\n' now
```

Should give you the epoch time in seconds. `now` can be some other common date specifications, including human representations common in the US, some ISO ones and even crontab time specifications.

`bash` copied a subset of that (only the formatting part, not the parsing part) in 4.2, and zsh's `$EPOCHSECONDS` in 5.0 (not `strftime`).